# How to reference the version information in a Google Chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I use

```
chrome.tabs.create({url:"URL here"})
```

to open a new tab in my LRG. To this URL I want to append the version number of the extension, which is specified in the `manifest.json` file:

```
"version": "1.2",
```

How can I access the version number in javascript at the time of creating the new tab?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fetch your own manifest and the version by using the following:

```
var url = chrome.extension.getURL("manifest.json");
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) {
  if(xhr.readyState == 2 && xhr.status == 200) {
     var manifest = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
     alert("Version: " + manifest.version);
  }
};

xhr.open("GET", url);
xhr.send();
```

Once you have the version number you can do your tab stuff that you need to do.

Comment: I use this and it works well. Here's a slightly more complete post on this method: http://martinsikora.com/accessing-manifest-json-in-a-google-chrome-extension

Comment: I can't actually recall why I used 2... I know I used it in the past for progress events.

Comment: Hi, i can ask here i think, is it possible to update extension/app when i check if update is available?

Answer (score 7):

Try in your extension:

```
chrome.app.getDetails().version
```

I don't know why it's not among [other APIs](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/api_index.html) but it works in my **Chrome 13 beta**. Rather test it in older versions of Chrome :).

EDIT: [It's probably a little buggy](http://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/group/chromium-extensions/browse_thread/thread/17e7a0d47e9a6399)

Comment: Get Details is not broadly available yet.

Comment: Can you provide me with some link? I'm quiet curious which versions of Chrome support it.

Comment: its now `chrome.runtime.getManifest()` see https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getManifest

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to comment but in regard to Kinlan's XMLHttpRequest answer:

I found this very useful, but I did notice it should wait for readyState == 4 (not 2).

Worked great for me and seems like it should be robust.