# What is the best way to retrieve a Google Chrome Extension ID?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I know two ways of getting Google Chrome Extension ID:

```js
chrome.app.getDetails().id;

chrome.i18n.getMessage('@@extension_id');
```

Are there any drawbacks regarding one of those?

I tend to use the first one since it's shorter but who knows. I may be wrong.

**---- EDIT ----**

Since I'm the only who cares, here's what I did to benchmark those:

```js
console.time('t1');
for (var i=0; i < 10000; i++) { chrome.app.getDetails().id; }; 
console.timeEnd('t1');

console.time('t2');
for (var i=0; i < 10000; i++) { chrome.i18n.getMessage('@@extension_id'); }; 
console.timeEnd('t2');
```

Here are the results:

```js
t1: 5190.766ms

t2: 860.697ms
```

It looks like **using i18n is so much faster overall** but the first one is faster at the beginning and after 3 or 4 executions, i18n is better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end, I created a small Chrome Extension to benchmark three known ways to retrieve Chrome Extension ID:

- `chrome.app.getDetails().id;`
- `chrome.i18n.getMessage('@@extension_id');`
- `chrome.extension.getURL('/').slice(19, -1);`
- `chrome.runtime.id;`

<strike>As you can see in the result below, `chrome.extension.getURL('/').slice(19, -1);` seems to spend less time overall **but** the first calls are equivalent to the other ones.</strike>

[image: Benchmark image for Google Chrome 27.0.1430.0 (Official Build 186115) dev]

As we can see, ***`chrome.runtime.id` wins***.

Note #1: You can download the zip archive of the extension [here](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0B8R1QvA3x5IbUFBQUWI2dktBMDA)

Note #2: I used `performance.now()` to get an accurate timing.

Note #3: I added `chrome.runtime.id` to the benchmark tool. Thanks Konstantin Smolyanin!

Answer (score 3):

Try to go through the similar query:
[How to reference the version information in a Google Chrome extension?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436039/how-to-reference-the-version-information-in-a-google-chrome-extension)

There you can get a broader idea of the first call, you are using.

```
    chrome.app.getDetails().id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Are you saying using chrome.app.getDetails() is bad since the scope is too large?

Comment: @ Francois...No it was the way I said that you can get what else you can get to know after you will read the link.  :)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that since chrome 22 the best way to get the extension ID is built-in property `chrome.runtime.id`. [See documentation.](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime.html#property-id)

```
console.log(chrome.runtime.id);
```