# How to read version of app in app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app

I want to read the app version stored in `manifest.json`:

```
...
"version": "0.1.0",
...
```

during the execution of the app (really just after loading) to display the app version.  I also do NOT want to have the version in multiple places because it can get out of sync.  Is there a way to read fields of the manifest while the app is executing?

Comment: possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436039/how-to-reference-the-version-information-in-a-google-chrome-extension

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is available through: `chrome.runtime.getManifest().version`

Documented [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getManifest).